# Is a rearrangement of a convergent sequence still convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Is a rearrangement of a convergent sequence still convergent?

I work in an arbitrary normed vector space.

I think this is the case.
Let $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ be a converging sequence with limit $L$.
Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection.
Define $y_i = x_{f(i)}$.

Then $(y_1, y_2, \ldots)$ is convergent with limit $L$.
Proof.
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ is convergent there exists an $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$ we have that $||x_n - L|| < \epsilon$.
Since $N$ is finite and $f$ is a bijection we have that the set
$\{f^{-1}(i)\, | \, i = 1, 2, \ldots, N \}$ is bound by some natural number $M$. Now let $m > M$. Then $f(m) > N$. So $||y_m - L|| = ||x_{f(m)} - L || < \epsilon$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the idea and execution just right! The only alterations I'd make involve type-setting, notation, and terminology adjustments.

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ is convergent there exists an $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$ we have that $||x_n - L|| < \epsilon$.

Here, rather than use `||x_n - L||`, I'd use `\lVert x_n-L\rVert`, instead giving us $\lVert x_n-L\rVert.$ For one thing, it looks a little better (my opinion, obviously), and renders more easily. Another, more important reason comes about if we want/need to adjust sizing. For example, let's say we're in the normed vector space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]\to\Bbb R,$ under the norm $$\lVert f\rVert:=\max\bigl\{f(t)\mid t\in[0,1]\bigr\},$$ and we want to find the norm of the function $F(t):=\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx$ for some suitable functions $f$ and $g.$ Now, it's clear just by looking that the standard bars won't be tall enough to encompass the integral, so we might try using the `\big` function to fix it. That turns out to work just fine, at first, giving us either $\big|\big|\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big|\big|$ if we typeset it as `\big|\big|\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big|\big|`, or get us $\big\lVert\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big\rVert$ if we typeset it as `\big\lVert\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big\rVert`. However, later on, we decide for one reason or another that we'd like to center our mathematical notation, which instead gives us $$\big|\big|\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big|\big|$$ if we typeset it as `\big|\big|\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big|\big|`, or  $$\big\lVert\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big\rVert$$ if we typeset it as `\big\lVert\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\big\rVert`. Clearly, we've got to adjust, so we decide to use the delimiters `\left` and `right`, instead. This yields $$\left|\left|\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\right|\right|,$$ if we typeset it as `\left|\left|\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\right|\right|`, or $$\left\lVert\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\right\rVert$$ if we typeset it as `\left\lVert\int_0^t\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)\,dx\right\rVert`. Thus, we're saved a bit of typing and some editing, which can really pile up if we have a long array of equations to adjust, instead. Still, that's all a matter of preference.

> Since $N$ is finite and $f$ is a bijection we have that the set
>   $\{f^{-1}(i)\, | \, i = 1, 2, \ldots, N \}$ is bound by some natural number $M$.

Here, I'd suggest some adjustment to your terminology. It isn't particularly meaningful to say that $N$ is finite in this context, as far as I can tell. When we say "there exists an $N>0$ such that...," we mean for $N$ to be a positive real/natural number, all of which are arguably "finite" in some sense. Instead, I'd say something like: "Since $\{k\in\Bbb N\mid 1\le k\le N\}$ is a bounded subset of $\Bbb N,$ then it is finite. Thus, since $f$ is a bijection on $\Bbb N,$ then $$f^{-1}\bigl[\{k\in\Bbb N\mid 1\le k\le N\}\bigr]=\bigl\{f^{-1}(k)\mid k\in\Bbb N,1\le k\le N\bigr\}$$ is also a finite subset of $\Bbb N,$ and so is bounded above by some $M\in\Bbb N.$"

You might need to justify the equality above, that bounded subsets of $\Bbb N$ are exactly the finite subsets of $\Bbb N,$ or that pre-images of finite sets under injections are finite, if you haven't proved them/seen them proved previously.

Note here that instead of the term "bound" (which I typically see used to indicate the numbers/elements providing limits on the set in question), I use the term "bounded" (meaning possessing such limits). However, you may just be using a different terminological convention than that with which I'm familiar.

> Now let $m > M$.

Here, we could be a little more careful, saying something to the effect of: "Now let $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $m>M.$" That way, we don't rely on the reader to infer that $m$ is an element of the domain of $f.$

> Then $f(m) > N$.

We could be more careful, here, too. Perhaps something like: "Since $m\notin f^{-1}\bigl[\{k\in\Bbb N\mid 1\le k\le N\}\bigr],$ then $f(m)\notin\{k\in\Bbb N\mid 1\le k\le N\}$ by definition of pre-image, so $f(m)\not\le N,$ and so $f(m)>N.$"

Nice work!

Comment: thank you! I always find it very usefull to improve on my mathematical communication skills!